# How do I access currently selected text from a bookmarklet, while on gmail.com

Tags: javascript, firefox, gmail, bookmarklet

I'm using FF 3.5.3 on Windows Vista.

This is my (edited for shortness) bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){
var text = window.content.getSelection().toString();
alert(text);
})();
```

Works, but not on gmail.com. Probably due to dynamicly generated content.

I'm aware of [this](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/02/21/getselection-returns-empty-in-google-mail/) workaround, but it only works for Firefox extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail using frames. Try:

```
document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentWindow.getSelection().toString();
```